# Not able to pull blog image in linkedin

Tags: drupal-7, linkedin-api

I'm implementing custom share buttons for LinkedIn, Facebook etc. using Drupal 7 at the following URL:
http://commandpartners.com/blog/5-traits-of-an-entrepreneurial-mindset

After a user clicks on the LinkedIn button, a LinkedIn popup opens, with the correct title and description.  However, the wrong image appears. I'm not able to understand why the correct blog image does not appear.

Where is LinkedIn pulling the image from?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe the image being used is an older image capture from your site. Did you have this older image on the site before? (the city skyline illustration)

Comment: This image is exist on server, I also rename this image on server and try to share this blog on linked but same image is displayed and I guess this is coming from linked cache.

I am not able to understand it not picked up blog image.